# phpMyAdmin can't export database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a VPS machine and I installed phpMyAdmin and inserted the database in. But now when I want to make a backup and export the database, it says:

> [image: Error code 500, Internal Server Error]

Here is the error.log: http://pastebin.com/44N4YcAk

> [Tue Jun 18 21:40:16 2013] [error] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Comment: your using a VPS, Why are you backing up with phpmyadmin ?|

Comment: run mysqldump from the command line.

Comment: The error comes from tcpdf.php. Are you trying to export as PDF?

Answer (score 10):

you should not be using phpmyadmin for this, you should be using mysqldump. from the command line its

```
mysqldump -uMYSQL-USER -h server -pMYSQL-USER database_name > /path-to-export
```

from a php script

```
$command = "mysqldump -uMYSQL-USER -h server -pMYSQL-USER database_name > /path-to-export/file.sql";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

this is easy to automate with a cronjob

Comment: Using phpmyadmin to export a database is perfectly legitimate and a core function of the software. The user didn't ask for your advice on his backup processes, he asked how to get PHPMyAdmin to export.

Answer (score 2):

It says at the bottom

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 22694,
```

Either your VPS is out of memory or your PHP settings are not allowing more than 16MB of memory to be allocated.

Increase the memory in php.ini or just use mysqldump

php.ini change

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

I strongly recomend using mysqldump though here is an extract from my backup script

```
#!/bin/bash
time=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
mysqldump -u mysqluser -pmysqlpassword --all-databases | 7za a -si database/backup-${time}.sql.7z -p7zpass
```

That saves the backup in a 7zip file protected by the password `7zpass`

Comment: Or the database is too big.  He may need to export it in chunks, a few tables at a time.

Comment: theres 4k rows - thats nothing

Answer (score 2):

Go through this post, it shows how to increase the memory; or just use command line to import:

[How to increase memory size for phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859833/how-to-increase-memory-size-for-phpmyadmin)

Comment: did you increase the memory and restarted your apache server ? or you tried the command line solution ?

Comment: i increase the momory and restart

Answer (score 2):

do this command:

```
nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php
```

press ctrl+w and find:

```
// now export the triggers (needs to be done after the data because
```

this command used twice in the file after this command you see nested if, so in the nested if change:

```
break 2;
```

to

```
break;
```

in both cases after this your export function will work well

Answer (score 1):

Tip:

Change the mysql engine to InnoDB instead of MyISAM, the main purpose is claiming storage after cleaning tables or dropping them.