# export mysql database schema and data using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to export a database with phpmyadmin but the result is a file that can't be read. In phpmyadmin I leave the options and only add compression. After downloading I'm unable to open the resulted .sql file (after extracting) in geany and get a complaint about the file being in an encoding that's not supported. Every time I do the export the file seems to be of a random size as if the process just stops somewhere.

It's a small database with joomla stuff that needs to be moved to another site and I would like to use mysldump but don't have ssh access. Other than the phpmyadmin in the cpanel I can't think of another way to access that data but phpmyadmin doesn't seem to be up for doing the job.

Is there any setting I should have to have a look at or some other way to get that data exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling compression or using another compression method. There have been a few bugs in phpMyAdmin. Maybe you are stumbling about one of them. Also try opening the sql file in an ordinary text editor and check the content maybe you can get some more information about the problem you are experiencing.

If you have access to the commandline you can also try the following command: `mysqldump -u <username> -p <database_name> > dumpfilename.sql`.

Comment: As the question states; don't have ssh access but the following helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17178274/1641941 basically used exec in PHP to execute mysqldump