# Importing wikipedia dump to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, dump

I am trying to import a .bz2 file into MySql database but I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 386400256) (tried to allocate 378535937 bytes) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.6.4\libraries\plugins\import\ImportXml.php on line 90
```

I tried so many solutions here including raising `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size`

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What's the size of the file and what are the values for the php.ini limits?

Comment: the file size is 115m , upload max size is 800 , memory limit 1 Go, and post max size is also 1 Go

Comment: Php is probably running out of memory as it decompresses the file. You should look into a streaming decompressor

Answer (score 6):

If you can, use MySQL directly without PHP:

```
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql.gz
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-redirect.sql.gz
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pagelinks.sql.gz
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-langlinks.sql.gz

gzip -d enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz
gzip -d enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz
gzip -d enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql.gz
gzip -d enwiki-latest-redirect.sql.gz
gzip -d enwiki-latest-pagelinks.sql.gz
gzip -d enwiki-latest-langlinks.sql.gz

# Don't need this if MySQL is configured correctly.
# SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;
# SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
# SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
# SET GLOBAL character_set_server = utf8mb4;
# SET NAMES utf8mb4;

CREATE DATABASE wiki_en; USE wiki_en;

# Don't need this if MySQL is configured correctly.
# ALTER DATABASE wiki_en CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-page.sql
mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-redirect.sql
mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-category.sql
mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql
mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-pagelinks.sql
mysql -u root -p wiki_en < enwiki-latest-langlinks.sql

# Indicative filesizes:
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    35G Jun  2 07:01 enwiki-latest-pagelinks.sql
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    13G Jun  2 07:45 enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   4.3G Jun  2 11:08 enwiki-latest-page.sql
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   900M Jun  2 11:03 enwiki-latest-langlinks.sql
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   378M Jun  2 11:10 enwiki-latest-redirect.sql
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   117M Jun  2 11:03 enwiki-latest-category.sql
```

If you really must use PHP, you need to set the memory limit for PHPMyAdmin (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16105949/2178980)), and also make sure you've run the MySQL above.

Comment: how to execute it?

Comment: What access do you have? Server? Through AWS? Your PC? UNIX? Windows? MySQL running on which port?

Comment: server V 5 on windows 3306

Comment: Well if you're on Windows, you can directly download the files using your browser, then you can manually unzip each one to get the .gz file.  Then, log into mysql, run the commands above (but not the ones starting with mysql). Once the DB is created, exit, and then run the mysql commands. Note, this will take a long time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am doing that exactly and facing the problem which I asked about

Comment: Oh. How much ram in your server?