# Shows Out of memory in Util.php on line 2302 in phpmyadmin of xampp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am facing some problem when I am trying to import sql database in phpmyadmin using xampp. It gives error given below

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 406847488) (tried to allocate 805306376 bytes) in E:\xamp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.php on line 2302

Do you have any suggestion? how we can solve this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase memory size for phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859833/how-to-increase-memory-size-for-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Thanks Peter for your suggestion , but its for util.php and that one is for import.lib.php.

Answer (score 1):

problem was made by large or crash import SQL file.

Go to `YOUR_ROOT/phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.php`
and on line 2301 before cycle for() write new line: `$nbTotalPage = (is_infinite($nbTotalPage)) ? 500 : $nbTotalPage;`